# asp.net mvc 3 EF HTML MultiSelect - How to retrieve multiple values using LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, multi-select

I have an Advanced Search form, It contains, input boxes, dropdown lists, etc. And now I want to change a dropdown list to a multiselect list.

I can set the view, like this:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.IdState, null, new { size = "7" })
```

But I don't know how to change the controller from:

```
public ActionResult Index(FormData model)
{
    IQueryable<mytable> results = from s in db.mytable.Include("State").where(s=> (model.IdState != null ? s.IdState == model.IdState : true)) select s;
    return View(result);
}
```

To a multiple IdState Result???

Earlier the IdState was:

```
int IdState;
```

Now is:

```
IEnumerable<int> IdState;
```

Thanks for your time!

**I still can't make it work. In SQL will be:**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE IdState IN (1,2,5,7,10)
```

Any Idea? The http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx Don't show similar situation

**Workaround**

I found on this discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/ this code snippet:

```
IQueryable<Foo> foos = context.Foo.Where("it.Id in {1, 2, 3, ...}");
```

I changed to

```
string sState = "";
foreach (int a in model.IdState ) sState += (a.ToString() + ",");
sState = sState .Substring(0, sState .Length - 1);
IQueryable<mytable> results = from s in db.mytable.Where("it.IdState in {" + sState + "}");
```

And It works great!!!

I hope can find the final solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
s.IdState == model.IdState
```

try using

```
model.IdState.Contains(s.IdState)
```

Comment: Thanks, I could compile with `model.IdState.Contains((int)s.IdState` but I'm getting _Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context_, On `results.ToPagedList(pageIndex-1, pageSize);` Because I'm using PagedList extension (I omitted to clarify)

Comment: Seems that I can only do simple comparations

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.0? `Contains` doesn't work in EFv1 - .NET 3.5. Also why do you convert `s.IdState` to `int`? Your model.IdState should be already correctly typed when you pass them to the query. You can also try to store `model.IdState` in a local variable and pass the local variable to the query instead of `model.IdState`.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm using .NET 4.0 with Razor. I didn't convert to s.IdState to int. The model is a "SearchResult" model to obtain the Form Data Results from the web. The IdState was the value from a DropDownList and now is a multiple value from a Multiple ListBox. I'm going to publish a workaround.

Comment: `Contains` is translated to SQL `IN` statement - it is what you want. Just make sure that you pass local array of ints or IEnumerable<int> to your query where you call something like `.Where(e => states.Contains(e.Id))`. It should work.

Comment: I tried but I get same error, I'm new on EF, I could check on Proyect Properties I'm using Framework 4.0 but how can I check EF version? Or that was enough?

Comment: I have to say that I don't know why it doesn't work in your scenario. The fact that ESQL `IN` operator works in your workaround shows that `Contains` should work as well because it is just translation of that operator to Linq-to-entities.